# Fill a combobox with a column in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

hi so im trying to fill a combobox with the values i have in a datagridview column and i came up with this code

```
'Dim i As Integer = 0
While i <> DataGridView1.Rows.Count
    ComboBox1.Items.Add((DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1)).Value).ToString()
    'MsgBox(((DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1)).Value).ToString())
    i = i + 1
End While
```

in the msgbox the values that i wanted to add appear right but for some reason it does not fill my combobox with nothing and my combobox stays empty any ideas why? ty

Comment: well nvm i figured out xD it was int the wrong sub ... well im letting stay this code might be usefull to someone xD my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
For Each rw In DataGridView1.Rows
     ComboBox1.Items.Add((rw.Cells(1)).Value).ToString()
Next
```

I suggest you use the `DataSource` property of the `DataGridView` to fill your `ComboBox` properly:

```
Dim Dt As DataTable = DataGridView1.DataSource
ComboBox1.DataSource = Dt
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = Dt.Columns(1).Caption
ComboBox1.ValueMember = Dt.Columns(0).Caption
```