# vbnet DataGridView set combobox one column with datasource

Tags: vb.net

i have some codes for get data from oracle table,
İ want one of column as combobox in table

```
Dim cm2 As New OleDbCommand("Select COL1,COL2,COL3 From TABLE", cn_oracle)
    With DGV_MEET
        Dim dt = New DataTable()
        myDA = New OleDbDataAdapter(cm2)
        Dim builder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(myDA)
        DS = New DataSet()
        myDA.Fill(DS, "TABLE")
        .DataSource = DS.Tables("TABLE").DefaultView
    
        .AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
        .RowsDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
     
    End With
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42716380/fill-a-combobox-with-a-column-in-datagridview

Comment: Thanks For return but
This is not my answer
i want one of colum in datagrid as combobox

Comment: Firstly, don't create a `DataSet` if all you need is a `DataTable`. Secondly, don't bind the `DefaultView` because that's where the data comes from anyway. Finally, add a `BindingSource` to your form, bind the `DataTable` to that and that to the `DataGridView`.

Comment: As for your question, the grid will never create a combo box column for you, so you always have to create it yourself. Find my example of how [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?541476).